# Cisco packet tracer making sure that configurations are correct

Tags: networking, cisco-packet-tracer

So I am doing a lab with cisco packet tracer now the check result button is super helpful, but I want to learn how to self check if everything is working without the help of the option.

This is the lab I am doing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you are trying to check. Generally if you can ping from one end to another your setup is working as desired.

Ultimately it depends on what exactly you are trying to check.

Comment: added an image to show should be more helpful

Comment: @zellez ty, looking at it, as long as you can run a ping command from the workstations to the router, server, etc, your network should be working. Ping is one of the most useful tools for checking that it is working.

Comment: ok, so I pinged from records-1 to the ip of State and it worked

Comment: @zellez then your network is working. That means that every device in between is functioning properly in order to pass the ping packet to the destination and receive the reply :)